# ST2 -- split_selection_into_lines -- left side of block

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

Is it possible to `split_selection_into_lines` at the **left** side of the block, instead of the right?

It would be nice to select several lines (in one fell swoop) and then type something that will precede each line.  I have been using the command+left-click for the left-hand margin, but it is difficult to know whether each line has actually been selected because each line is vertically aligned (e.g., flush-left) -- it is also time consuming to select each line manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After selecting "split_selection_into_lines" (ctrl+shift+l), the keyboard shortcut command+left-arrow moves multiple cursors the left side of the highlighted block.

Alternatively, holding down the option(alt) key and holding down the left click on the mouse lets the user select everything within a vertical line that is defined by moving the mouse up or down.

https://tutsplus.com/lesson/multiple-cursors-and-incremental-search/

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to just find-replace, and replace a delimiter with "\n [text that precedes this line]"

Comment: Ah . . . I may need to write my own plugin to make this happen with a keyboard shortcut . . . perhaps I could take the existing plugin that handles `split_selection_into_lines` and modify it to work for the left side of the selected block.